# What are the Camel constructs for "long-running routes"?

Tags: apache-camel

We are investigating Camel for use in a new system; one of our situations is that a set of steps is started, and some of the steps in the set can take hours or days to execute. We need to execute other steps after such long-elapsed-time steps are finished.

We also need to have the system survive reboot while some of the "routes" with these steps are in progress, i.e., the system might be rebooted, and we need the "routes" in progress to remain in their state and pick up where they left off.

I know we can use a queued messaging system such as JMS, and that messages put into such a queue can be handled to be persisted. What isn't clear to me is how (or whether) that fits into Camel -- would we need to treat the step(s) after each queue as its own route, so that it could, on startup, read from the queue? That's going to split up our processing steps into many more 'routes' than we would have otherwise, but maybe that's the way it's done.

Is/are there Camel construct/constructs which assist with this kind of system? If I know their terms and basic outline, I can probably figure it out, but what I really need is an explanation of what the constructs do.

Answer (score 3):

Camel is not a human workflow / long-lasting tasks system. For that kind look at BPMS systems. Camel is more fitting for real time / near real time integrations.

For long tasks you persist their state in some external system like a message broker or database or BPMS, and then you can use Camel routes to process and move from one state to the next - or where Camel fit in such as integrating with the many different systems you can do OOTB with the 200+ Camel components.

Camel do provide graceful shutdown so you can safely shutdown or reboot Camel. But in the unlikely event of a crash, you may want to look at transactions and idempotency if you are talking about *surviving a system crash*.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to asynchronous processing of messages in routes. Camel has a couple of components that you can use to achieve this.

- SEDA: In memory not persistent and can only call end points in the same route.
- VM: In memory not persistent and can call endpoints in different camel contexts but limited to the same JVM. This component is a extension of SEDA.
- JMS: Persistence is  configurable on the queue stack. Much more heavy weight but also more fault tolerant than SEDA/JVM.

SEDA/JVM can be used as low overhead replacements for JMS components and in some cases I would use them exclusively. In your case the persistence element is a required so SEDA/JVM is not an option, but to keep things simple the examples will use SEDA as you can get some basics up and running quickly.

The example will assume the following we  have a timer that kicks off and then there is two processes it needs to run. See screenshot below:

[image]

In this route the message flow is synchronous between the timer and the two process beans.

If we wanted to make these steps asynchronous we would need to break each step into a route of its own. We would then connect these routes using one of the components listed in the beginning. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Notice we have three routes each route only has one "processing" step in it. Route Test only has a timer which fires a messages to the SEDA queue called processOne. This message is received on the SEDA queue and sent to the Process_One bean. After this it is the send to the SEDA queue called processTwo, where it is received and passed to the Process_Two bean. All this is done asynchronously.

You can replace the SEDA components with JMS once you get to understand the concepts. I suspect that state tracking is going to be the most complicated part as Camel makes the asynchronous part easy.